# I'm getting no output from the Image node when using sverchok

Tags: image, sverchok

Nothing on output in Image node (Image Decompose too). I have tried different types and sizes of images, but still can't get result from this node. May be there is some special requirments on images used with this node?

Screenshot:
[image: image node sverchok]

And this is how it should look when node function properly:

[image: working image node]

Comment: It's totally unclear to me what you're having an issue with. An image node could be for a blender internal shader, for a cycles shader, for compositing etc... Then it would help to know how you're trying to use this node, what other nodes it's connected to, what is the behaviour that you expect and what is the behaviour that you're seeing. Please show a screenshot of your node setup or upload your blend file, so ppl here can help you figure out this issue.

Comment: @coCoKNIght Note that the question is tagged with 'sverchok', an add-on for blender.

Answer (score 2):

The Image Decompose node (a beta node) requires the first 2 output sockets to be connected, before it produces any output. The docs mention this: http://nikitron.cc.ua/sverch/html/nodes/beta/image_decompose.html

I wrote this node and admit that this requirement is not the most intuitive, and should probably be revised.

---

But regarding the Image Node (in Generators), if you open the System Console and see the output of Sverchok you'll get an error, which hints at the problem. A bug.

```
File "C:\Users\....\sverchok\nodes\generator\image.py", line 112, in process
    if 'edgs' in self.outputs and len(self.outputs['edgs'].is_linked) > 0:
    Node Image had exception object of type 'bool' has no len()
```

i'll file a [sverchok bug report about that](https://github.com/nortikin/sverchok/issues/777) -- this is fixed in the next update.

[image]